# Don't want iframe to take up 100% width after 759px

Tags: css, iframe, responsive

I have a problem with youtube iframe videos.  I want the iframe to take up the 100% width of the page and maintain aspect ratio on mobile devices.  I do not want the video to get bigger than its 560 width or 315 height.  I then want the 2 videos to be displayed inline-block on a tablet and for the desktop.  I want the iframes side by side on a tablet and desktop.  I can't seem to figure this out.  I have exhaustively searched this and can't find an answer that works.  Here is my code.

HTML

```
<div class="video_responsive">
 <div class="video-container">
  <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/9_zGXEmNKPo" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
 </div>
 <div class="video-container">
  <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/zEI8CT7cElQ" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
 </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.video_responsive{
  padding-left: 1em;
  padding-right: 1em;
}
.video-container{
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 56.25%;
  padding-top: 35px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.video-container iframe{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.  I am doing this for a class.  Professor has no idea how to fix this problem.  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Update 2

OP mentioned an interest in tables. Although they can make a layout simple, it's not meant for layout, they're meant to represent data. Fortunately, there's are several `display` values that allow an element to  behave like a table. On both demos, when in desktop mode, the posters (images displayed when video is idle) overlap and are distorted, but the video isn't.

The most important ones are:

- `table` element will behave like `<table>`
- `table-row` element will behave like `<tr>`
- `table-cell` element will behave like `<td>`

Here's an [article](http://www.mattboldt.com/kicking-ass-with-display-table/) with tips on how to use `display: table`

This [**Plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/gy3sj46fmEvFl4iSJkpZ?p=preview) is using `display: table/table-cell`

---

## Update 1

The code editor on this site isn't good for complex CSS so I moved the demo over to **[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/0nc5sfgHtWXWZts3gkNt?p=preview)**

### Summary

- 2 major properties in use are:

  - [media query](https://www.google.com/search?q=media%20query&oq=media%20query&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i59&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)
  - [flexbox](https://scotch.io/tutorials/a-visual-guide-to-css3-flexbox-properties)
- Mobile mode 758px or less in width for viewport

  - flexbox layout is stacked (`flex-flow: column nowrap`)
- Desktop mode 759px or more in width for viewport

  - media query triggers at 759px or more
  - `flex-flow` is now `row nowrap`

---

Use media query:

```
 @media only screen and (min-width: 759px) {
   .video_responsive {
     display: table;
     }
  .video-cpntainer {
    display: table-cell;
    max-width: 45vw;
 }
```

```css
.video_responsive {
  padding-left: 1em;
  padding-right: 1em;
}
.video-container {
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 56.25%;
  padding-top: 35px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.video-container iframe {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
  @media only screen and (min-width: 759px) {
   .video_responsive {
 flex-flow: row nowrap;
 }
.video-container {
  min-width: 380px;
  max-width: 48vw;
  min-height: 214px;
  max-height: 27vh;
 }
 }
```

```html
<div class="video_responsive">
  <div class="video-container">
    <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/9_zGXEmNKPo" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  </div>
  <div class="video-container">
    <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/zEI8CT7cElQ" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @zerOOne I tried the above and it did get them on the same line but they overlap.  Is using a table considered good practice in responsive design today?

Comment: @thomasna82 See updated Plunker. Don't use a table for layout no matter how tempting it may be. You can use the several `display` properties that allow other elements to behave like a table ;-)

Comment: this almost works.  I have an image that is taking up 100vh at the top of my page.  The fixed position places the video over that.  How can I get the videos back down under the top image?

Comment: You can change `fixed` to relative, that shouldn't break anything. I made a demo that uses `display: table/table-cell` if you are interested.

Comment: This works using your flexbox layout.  Changing the position from fixed to relative works.  How did you come up with the padding-top and bottom of 16% and margin 4%'s?

Comment: The width in your aspect ratio is a factor of 16 and I set the boxes to 48vw  and of course height will be a factor of 9 and height is 27vh. Using vw and vh will make their lengths flexible yet true to their aspect ratio. Normally, you must depend on 56.25% of padding to get a flexible yet true to AR height. Since you have control of the height, you have a finer grain of control with the padding. The 16% and 4% are for positioning in this case and using a base of 16 works almost all the time...for me at least.

Answer (score 1):

In your CSS set `max-width: 759px;` for your iframe.

Comment: It does not scale up or down responsively.  The iframes get cut half off scaling down and when scaling up the iframe grows enormously in height.  Is there a way to make it go no bigger than the original dimensions of 560 X 315?

Comment: You can use JavaScript or jQuery to set the size of it when the page loads and then remove the CSS that would affect the dimensions of the iframe when the window changes size.